# Designing an algorithm that keeps traffic equally distributed over a network

Tags: algorithm, logic, pseudocode, traffic, divide-and-conquer

My question isn't related to how to code a particular thing or any technical programming question. I need help in developing a logic of an algorithm that I am working on which I will be explaining in a bit. I am here because I couldnt think of a better place than stackoverflow to help me out as it has proved the best option in the past. I would like to thank you guys for helping your me out and giving me your precious time.

So here goes my brain teasing algorithm:

**Aim :**
I am developing an algorithm that aims to equally distribute traffic(cars) over a network. I will be simulating this algorithm to check how it works on some traffic simulator.

To put it visually what I am planning to do I have included this image:

[Plotting the traffic network which shows that some roads are populated than the others. Thicker lines indicate roads that have more traffic as compared to others.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1s0y.png)

**Here are some points to note :**

1. The image represents 8*8 junctions(intersection of roads) and the roads themselves. Not good with my graphic skills so just wanted to make clear that 4 roads meet up to make a junction(not clearly shown in diagram, but you get what I mean).
2. Notice the directed arrows, those indicate the direction in which the traffic will be moving. For example, the first row indicates the traffic will be moving from right to left. Second row indicates the traffic will move from left to right. Similary, the first column represents that traffic will more from bottom to top etc. If you observe closely, you will notice that I have kept an alternate pattern ie. right to left,then left to right, then again right to left etc. Similar is the case for columns.
3. No turning of vehicles is allowed. Since, this is the initial stages of my algorithm I have put a restriction that vehicles are not allowed to turn and continue in the direction of the arrow.
4. This is a loop-around type network. Meaning, the cars after reaching the extremes of the network do not vanish away, they loop around and are fed again into the network. Keep in mind, the cars are fed in the direction of arrow. For example in first row, after the cars leave from the left-most junction, the cars will join in again into the right-most junction. Simply to say, it is some sort of wrapping around or mesh kind of thing.
5. The traffic is created randomly and as the image suggests thicker the lines, the more traffic on that road and vice-versa.
6. **Important:** When at a junction, if we are to allow cars to pass from left to right (horizontally) all the cars moving in vertical direction will have to be stopped (obvious so that they don't crash into each other) and vice-versa.

**What I need help in:**

1. Pseudocode/Logic for the algorithm which allows me to equally distribute the traffic in the network (graphically lines of almost the same thickness as per my image). Mathematically, the thickness of the line will be average number of cars that should be on each road so that the whole network is balanced. Roads, should be equally populated, no road should have more traffic than the other (fairness policy).
2. I wanted to solve the problem using a divide and conquer approach. Meaning, in real world the network will be very big so it is almost impossible to have the information of the whole network with us at any given moment of time.

I want to solve the problems locally and round-wise.

**For example**, Round 1: Solve 4 junctions at a time and try to equalize the traffic at them.

Round 2: Some other 4 junctions

and so on...

**Tip:** The effect should propagate as the rounds advances reaching to some optimal solution where the traffic is equally distributed and then we stop the algorithm.

I know this is a long post and I really appreciate anyone who even tried to understand my objective and gave a thought about it.

This idea popped into my head giving because of the growing traffic situations and that there are some roads that are less populated than the others and so equally distribute the cars and take more advantage of the available infrastructure.

Comment: Maybe you take a look at all what the TCP protocol offers? Congestion control etc...
(www.google.de/search?q=tcp+congestion+algorithm)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you control in this setup? The cars only go forward in the predefined pattern. The layout is fixed. The car density is random.